# What is the name or ID of this mechanical part with multiple pin connection points?

Tags: part-identification

Trying to locate this particular piece on BrickLink though I’m not having very much luck. It’s appears to be a grey bar piece/ zip line bar of some sort. Any assistance you can provide is greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I think this is [Part # 30375 : Torso Mechanical, Battle Droid](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30375&idColor=59#T=C&C=59)

[image]